# Does a finite commutative ring with $n$ unit elements have at most $(n + 1)^2$ elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I want to solve this problem:

> A finite commutative ring with $n$ unit elements has at most $(n + 1)^2$ elements.

Is there any hint to prove this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related for zero divisors instead of units: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430193

Comment: This is not true : $\Bbb F_2^{n}$ has only one unit but has cardinality $2^n$.

Comment: @Watson Well, beaten by 9 seconds...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does not seem to be true.

Let $\mathbb{F}_2$ be a field with $2$ elements, and consider the ring $R = \prod_{j=1}^m \mathbb{F}_2$, where $m\geq 3$.  Then $R$ has $2^m$ elements, even though it has only one unit.

Comment: Just in case you would be interested: a finite commutative unital ring with only one unit is [isomorphic to](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/688140) a direct product of $\Bbb F_2$.

Comment: @Watson Nice find!